# How to read csv into table with custom header?

Tags: csv

I want to read a csv into a table that I defined like follows:

```
\begin{table}[bp]
    \centering
    \caption{Reading csv.}
    \label{table:csv}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{1.4cm}{\parbox{1\linewidth}{\vspace{1mm}A}} & \multirow{2}{0.9cm}{\parbox{1\linewidth}{\vspace{1mm} \centering B}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
    & & D & E  \\ \midrule
    A0      &   B0      &   D0      &   E0 \\
    A1      &   B1      &   D1      &   E1 \\
    A2      &   B2      &   D2      &   E2 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The .csv looks like:

```
,B,C,
,,D,E
A0,B0,D0,E0
A1,B1,D1,E1
A2,B2,D2,E2
```

And the table should look like:

[image]

1. How can I read the .csv?
2. How can A be centered in the column?
3. Should the .csv contain the headers of the table (A, B, C, D and E) or that should come from latex only?

Thanks for the help

EDIT:
Would it be easier/better if the .csv looks like this?

```
A,B,D,E
A0,B0,D0,E0
A1,B1,D1,E1
A2,B2,D2,E2
```

Comment: Do you have control over producing the CSV? If not, will it *always* be produced in this way?

Comment: I can make it however I want, that is why I asked question 3. It might be better to have:
```
A,B,D,E
A0,B0,D0,E0
A1,B1,D1,E1
A2,B2,D2,E2
```
right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool,booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{table_data.csv}
A,B,D,E
A0,B0,D0,E0
A1,B1,D1,E1
A2,B2,D2,E2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \DTLloaddb{tabledata}{table_data.csv}% Load CSV data
  \centering
  \caption{Reading csv.}
  \begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
    \toprule
      &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    A & B & D & E  \\
    \midrule
    \DTLforeach{tabledata}{%
      \Acol=A,
      \Bcol=B,
      \Dcol=D,
      \Ecol=E%
    }{%
      \Acol & \Bcol & \Dcol & \Ecol \\
    }
    \\[-\normalbaselineskip] \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks great. Thanks!
One last thing is when the values of A are more than 2 characters, A is aligned to the left. How do you add the columns and their headings?

Comment: And what is the reason to use datatool and not csvsimple?

Comment: @aripod: The headers should be `c`entred as that is how it is in the `tabular` column specification. I use [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) because I'm more familiar with it than with [`csvsimple`](//ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple). You can create "databases" with it, sort entries and process them. `csvsimple` is probably just a more elementary implementation that works just as well for your purposes.